# Groceries dataset: List transaction with only n items

Tags: r, data-science, arules

this is a special question and since I have been for lot of weeks of research I didn't found any answer.

The dataset is Groceries I get with this commands:

```
install.packages("arules")
library(arules)
data(Groceries)
```

I try to show the number of transactions that have n items them (in R with R Studio). 
I am completely stuck. I though at first creating a rule.... but I'm still stuck at this step.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What kind of format that is?

Comment: It's a sparce matrix format!

Comment: I have no clue on how the class `transactions` with attribute `arules` works. I think a more careful reading of the documentation would help. Look [here](https://rpubs.com/Mentors_Ubiqum/Filter_Transactions).

Comment: I will give it a try!

Comment: It didn't help for this case, but it helped me for another one. I'm still stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it! Let me know if this is what you meant!

```
n_items <- 4
large_transactions <- Groceries[size(Groceries) > n_items]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!  It is the answer I was looking for!